# Confusion with typedef and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typedef pointers a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/typedef-pointers-a-good-idea)

I am confused with the following:

```
typedef struct body *headerptr;
```

Now, when I create something with type headptr that points to a struct body, to create a new headerptr would be as follows (I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly):

```
headerptr newHeadptr;
```

Am I correct to assume that this would be a pointer that points to a struct body?

Comment: Try it.  If it works, great.  If it doesn't come back here.

Comment: Alright. Well, the compiler doesn't seem to be complaining, and it does work. Just not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. `headerptr` is now equivalent to `struct body*`.

Answer (score 2):

> This would be a pointer that points to a struct body.

The way you've declared it, `newHeadptr` *could* point to a `struct body`. Remember, though, that you haven't allocated a `struct body` for it to point to. Initially, `newHeadptr` will just have some garbage value. To rectify that, you could to this:

```
headerptr newHeaderptr = malloc(sizeof(*newHeaderptr));
```

or:

```
struct body newBody;
headerptr newHeaderptr = &newBody;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I already defined it already but I didn't post it. ;D

Comment: Might be clearer to do `headerptr newHeaderptr = malloc(sizeof *newHeaderptr)`

Comment: @ChrisLutz, that's a good point.